# OrientDB ClassCastException

Tags: document, orientdb, classcastexception

I get the following exception when trying to access a relationship document:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.id.ORecordId cannot be cast to com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument
```

via:

```
Collection<ODocument> field = myDoc.field("MY_FIELD_NAME");
        if(field != null) {
            return field;
        } else {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }
```

The strange thing is that is happes not always, most of the time it works like expected.

Answer (score 0):

Depending by what the field contains, you could use the interface `OIdentifiable` instead of `ODocument`.
Try using:

```
Collection<OIdentifiable> field = myDoc.field("MY_FIELD_NAME");
if(field != null) {
    return field;
} else {
    return Collections.emptySet();
}
```

Comment: the field contains a collection of other ODocuments, its a classic (bi-)directional relationship.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help very much, since I need the ODocument instance. With an OIdentifiable you cannot do a lot..

Comment: You should take the record by executing a `identifiable.getRecord()`. This always works, either if you have ORecordId or ODocument.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But now I get null:
OIdentifiable identifiable = document.field(FIELD);
   ODocument result = identifiable.getRecord();
   if(result == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException();
   }
   return result;